# Granting Permission to use TTY Ports

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, tty

I'm trying to grant permission to my user account to use a couple of `tty` devices so that I don't need to use `sudo` to interact with them. These are the properties on the ports in question.

```
9303 0 crw--w---- 1 root tty 238, 1 Apr 17 12:32 /dev/ttyTHS1
25951 0 crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Apr 17 12:32 /dev/ttyUSB0
25952 0 crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Apr 17 12:32 /dev/ttyUSB1
25953 0 crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 2 Apr 17 12:32 /dev/ttyUSB2
25954 0 crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 3 Apr 17 12:32 /dev/ttyUSB3
25955 0 crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 4 Apr 17 12:32 /dev/ttyUSB4`
```

When I check the groups that my user account belongs to, I see both the `dialout` and `tty` groups there.

But when I try to run minicom

`minicom -d /dev/USB1`

I get a permission denied error. IF I do the same thing with `sudo` it works fine. What am I missing that will allow me to access the ports without using `sudo` (I'm avoiding granting permissions to everyone).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer. For some reason, when opening /dev/ttyUSB1 the device also opens /dev/tty8, which did not have permissions to be accessed by a group.